# Iteratively insert values from params

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a list of around 10 parameters (key-value-pairs) that I want to apply on an XML document.

Whenever it finds `TESTWORD` as a value, take the following key and replace that with the appropriate value. Also replace the name of that node.

**Input:**

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Homer</FirstName>
      <LastName>Simpson</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Springfield</City>
         <Note>TESTWORD key1</Note> <!-- change this -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
      <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
      <ContactNo>0987654321</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Quahog</City>
         <Note>TESTWORD key2</Note> <!-- change this -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
</Company>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Homer</FirstName>
      <LastName>Simpson</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Springfield</City>
         <NewElem>My new value</NewElem> <!-- changed -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
      <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
      <ContactNo>0987654321</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Quahog</City>
         <NewElem>Another value</NewElem> <!-- changed -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
</Company>
```

---

**My XSLT approach:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />

    <!-- Param list -->
    <xsl:param name="key1" select="'My new value'" />
    <xsl:param name="key2" select="'Another value'" />
    <!-- ... more params -->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Note[.='TESTWORD key1']"> <!-- iterate all params -->
        <xsl:element name="NewElem">
            <xsl:value-of select="$key1" /> <!-- replace all values -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first occurence `<Note>TESTWORD key1</Note>` is correctly replaced by `<NewElem>My new value</NewElem>`. But not the remaining occurrences.

---

I could just copy x-times this piece:

```
<xsl:template match="Note[.='TESTWORD keyX']">
   <xsl:element name="NewElem">
      <xsl:value-of select="$keyX" />
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But maybe there's an iterative approach?

---

PS: I'm using **Java**.

Comment: Do you intend to populate these parameters at runtime? Or can the values be hard-coded in the stylesheet? (Either way, you should be using a **key**: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key)

Comment: @michael.hor257k: The keys are static, the values are coming dynamically from another source.

Comment: Could you put these values in another XML document and read them from there?

Comment: @michael.hor257k: It would need to be an extra step. They are coming from a remote source as JSON.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Getting the values to my XSLT file is not the problem. I just don't know, how to iterate those params later.

Comment: Which XSLT processor is that? XSLT  2 allows sequences of strings and XSLT 3 even can process JSON as XDM maps and arrays.

Comment: @user1170330 There is no need to iterate if you're using a key.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Currently I'm using Java's native XSLT Processor. It appears to be Version 1.0 (?). If it would make thing easier, I could consider, using SAXON, which uses 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

With Saxon 9.8 and later you could declare a parameter of the XSLT 3/XPath 3.1 type `map(xs:string, xs:string)` (i.e. a map with string keys and values) to represent your key/value pairs. You could then process them and use them in match patterns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="map"
             as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
             select="map { 
                        'key1' : 'My new value',
                        'key2' : 'Another value' 
                    }"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="map-keys" select="map:keys($map)"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Note[some $key in $map-keys satisfies . = 'TESTWORD ' || $key]">
      <NewElemen>
          <xsl:value-of select="$map($map-keys[current() = 'TESTWORD ' || .])"/>
      </NewElemen>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsU

From Java there are ways to construct such an XdmMap from similar Java collections e.g. `makeMap` (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmMap.html#makeMap-java.util.Map-) converts a java.util.Map to an XdmMap.

It recommended to use the s9api and Xslt30Transformer with Saxon 9.8 or later to run XSLT 3, then you can set parameters on that class instance witg http://saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#setStylesheetParameters-java.util.Map-

You can however also pass in an `XdmMap` using the JAXP `Transformer` if Saxon is on the classpath:

```
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource("map-test1.xsl"));
    
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("key2", "value passed in from JAXP API");
    
    transformer.setParameter("map", XdmMap.makeMap(map1));
    
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource("input-sample1.xml"), new StreamResult(System.out));
```