# Passing Map to XSLT and changing values by keys

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a `Map` with several entries that I want to apply on an XML document, using XSLT.

Whenever it finds `TESTWORD` in the XML, take the following key and replace that with the appropriate value from the map. Also replace the name of that node.

**Input:**

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Homer</FirstName>
      <LastName>Simpson</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Springfield</City>
         <Note>TESTWORD key1</Note> <!-- change this -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
      <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
      <ContactNo>0987654321</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Quahog</City>
         <Note>TESTWORD key2</Note> <!-- change this -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
</Company>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Homer</FirstName>
      <LastName>Simpson</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Springfield</City>
         <NewElem>my value</NewElem> <!-- changed -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
      <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
      <ContactNo>0987654321</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Quahog</City>
         <NewElem>another value</NewElem> <!-- changed -->
      </Address>
   </Employee>
</Company>
```

---

**Java:**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "my value");
map.put("key2", "another value");

try {
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("doc.xslt"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    transformer.setParameter("map", map); // Passing map as parameter

    Source text = new StreamSource(new File("doc.xml"));
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("newXml.xml")));
} catch (URISyntaxException | TransformerException ex) {}
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />

    <xsl:key name="map" /> <!-- the map with my keys and values -->

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Note[.='TESTWORD key1']"> <!-- iterate all params -->
        <xsl:element name="NewElem">
            <xsl:value-of select="$key1" /> <!-- replace all values -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    <xsl:template match="Note[.='TESTWORD key2']">
        <xsl:element name="NewElem">
            <xsl:value-of select="$key2" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
    -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here you can check it: http://xsltransform.net/3N7GxDd

Comment: The part declaring `<xsl:key name="map" /> <!-- the map with my keys and values -->` doesn't make any sense. A key is not the tool to pass in a map from the host language to XSLT. The only way passing in a map is where you have an equivalent construct in XSLT/XPath, i.e. in XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 or later. But you would use an `xsl:param` as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62996659/252228 and you would need to convert the Java map to an XdmMap.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it using XSLT 1.0 and using Xalan in the XSLT:

I created a simple class that holds a static map:

```
package samples;

import java.util.Map;

public class StaticMap {
    private static Map<String, String> map;
    
    public static Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    
    public static void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        StaticMap.map = map;
    }
     
    public static String getValue(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Instead of passing the map to the XSLT, I loaded the map to my static map class:

```
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("key1", "my value");
            map.put("key2", "another value");

            try {
                TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\doc.xslt"));
                Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
                StaticMap.setMap(map);

                Source text = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\doc.xml"));
                transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\newXml.xml")));
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Here is my XSLT.  Note that in your XSLT, the template for Node was matching on elements with text values of 'TESTWORD key1', and I changed this to just look for values starting with 'TESTWORD':

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:staticMap="xalan://samples.StaticMap"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />


    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Note[substring(., 1, 8) = 'TESTWORD']"> <!-- iterate all params -->
        <xsl:element name="NewElem">
            <xsl:value-of select="staticMap:getValue(substring(.,10))" /> <!-- replace all values -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Company>
       
    <Employee>
              
        <FirstName>Homer</FirstName>
              
        <LastName>Simpson</LastName>
              
        <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
              
        <Address>
                     
            <City>Springfield</City>
                     
            <NewElem>my value</NewElem>
             
            <!-- change this -->
                  
        </Address>
           
    </Employee>
       
    <Employee>
              
        <FirstName>Peter</FirstName>
              
        <LastName>Griffin</LastName>
              
        <ContactNo>0987654321</ContactNo>
              
        <Address>
                     
            <City>Quahog</City>
                     
            <NewElem>another value</NewElem>
             
            <!-- change this -->
                  
        </Address>
           
    </Employee>
    
</Company>
```

Comment: Please note, that you use Xalan in your answer: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

Comment: @user1170330, I have updated my answer to include that Xalan was used.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> My version (XSLT 2.0) sets `xsl:param` inside of the template.

```
    <xsl:param name="key1"/>
    <xsl:param name="key2"/>
    <xsl:param name="key3"/>
    <xsl:param name="key4"/>
    <xsl:template match="Note[contains(.,'TESTWORD key1')]">
         <xsl:element name='{$elemName}'>
    <xsl:value-of select="$key1" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Note[contains(.,'TESTWORD key2')]">
         <xsl:element name='{$elemName}'>
    <xsl:value-of select="$key2" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Note[contains(.,'TESTWORD key3')]">
         <xsl:element name='{$elemName}'>
    <xsl:value-of select="$key3" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Note[contains(.,'TESTWORD key4')]">
         <xsl:element name='{$elemName}'>
    <xsl:value-of select="$key4" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

> When Java `setParameter` is invoked, I pass the values | parameters externally to XSL stylesheet.

```
        // create Transformer
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
        // set parameters
        transformer.setParameter("key1", "replaced value1");
        transformer.setParameter("key2", "replaced value2");
        transformer.setParameter("key3", "replaced value3"); 
        transformer.setParameter("key4", "replaced value4");
```

> **Martin Honnen** XSLT 3.0 version:

```
    <xsl:param name="map" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
        select="
            map {
            'key1': 'replaced value1',
            'key2': 'replaced value2',
            'key3': 'replaced value3',
            'key4': 'replaced value4'
            }"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:variable name="map-keys" select="map:keys($map)"/>

    <xsl:template
        match="
            Note[some $key in $map-keys
                satisfies . = 'TESTWORD ' || $key]">
        <xsl:element name='{$elemName}'>
            <xsl:value-of select="$map($map-keys[current() = 'TESTWORD ' || .])"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

> Logging:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/ml/fiona/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.16/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

writing /xslt/employee.xml to database allegro... on 2020-07-23T15:27:50.805440900

Total One document(s) in One batch is completed on 2020-07-23T15:27:51.115639400 

User audited as 'super' has modified /xslt/employee.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Company>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      <ContactNo>007007</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Lincolnshire</City>
         <nameOnChanged>replaced value1</nameOnChanged>
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      <ContactNo>007009</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Putney</City>
         <nameOnChanged>replaced value2</nameOnChanged>
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      <ContactNo>007000</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Oxfordshire</City>
         <nameOnChanged>replaced value3</nameOnChanged>
      </Address>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
      <ContactNo>007001</ContactNo>
      <Address>
         <City>Glasgow</City>
         <nameOnChanged>replaced value4</nameOnChanged>
      </Address>
   </Employee>
</Company>
```

Comment: What exactly is the benefit? I still need to specify every matching separately:     `<xsl:template match="Note[.='TESTWORD key1']">...</xsl:template>`. Also, when using `xsl:variable` instead of `xsl:param`, I can't pass the parameter from Java.

Comment: Please see the revision. (I refactor the xml content…Sorry, I am in the habit of doodling while thinking…)
`xsl:variable` and `xsl:param` is syntactically similar. But the technique is rather different…
`@Martin Honnen` `(no offense intended)` :  For although `map:keys($map)` works in my Oxygen, it fails in Java API. Looks like a combability issue with XSLT 3. So that `XdmMap` efficacy remains to be seen…

Comment: @FionaChen, I suggested the use of XdmMap for  XSLT 3 with Saxon 9.8 and later and using its `s9api`. The Java platform itself only has an XSLT 1 processor so it certainly won't allow the use of XPath 3.1 maps, independent of the API you use.